# Parameters input from responseJSON to responseDecodable using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, strava

I'm doing a .get request on [Get Activity Streams (getActivityStreams) - Strava API](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Streams-getActivityStreams) using Alamofire.

I was using the .responseJSON method but since it will be deprecated in Alamofire 6 I am trying to switch to using the .responseDecodable however I am facing some issues.
I have to inputs specific parameters in the request as an array of string

```
["keys": "latlng,time,altitude"]
```

This was my previous code that is functional

```
var headers : HTTPHeaders {
                  get {
                      return [
                          "Accept": "application/json",
                      ]
                  }
              }
    let url_activity = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/IDXXXX/streams"
    let params: [String: Any] =  [ "keys" : "latlng,time,altitude"]
    let head = HTTPHeaders(["Authorization" : "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"]) 
    AF.request(url_activity, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: head).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response.value)
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I have declared a new struct and made it conform to the Encodable/Decodable protocol to handle these parameters and also used the `encoder:JSONParameterEncoder.default` in the request like [in the example](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters)

```
struct DecodableType: Codable {
    let keys: [String: String]
}
let decode = DecodableType(keys: [ "keys" : ["latlng,time,altitude"]])
```

I have tried several versions like `["keys": "latlng,time,altitude"]` or `["keys" : ["latlng","time","altitude"]]` without any success, here is the new request :

```
        AF.request(url_act,
               method: .get,
               parameters: decode,
               encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default ,
               headers: head).responseDecodable(of: DecodableType.self) {
        response in
        // Same as before
```

Here is the error code, I know it's related to 2019 Apple policy that making a GET request with body data will fail with an error but I can't find a solution

> urlRequestValidationFailed(reason:
> Alamofire.AFError.URLRequestValidationFailureReason.bodyDataInGETRequest(33
> bytes))

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Use cURLDescription from Alamofire. You should see what's the difference in the request construction (previous & last). Since `responseDecodable()` is just for decoding, while your issue is while creating the request. Yu should keep it the same way, just replacing `responseJSON` with `responseDecodable`. Why change that part?

Comment: Did use the cURL description but the URL ended up being the same in both cases. Just replacing `responseJSON` with `responseDecodable` still requires a `DecodableType`, if I use one with `[String: String"]` I am now getting a new SwiftDecodingError  `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead`. Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried the cURLDescription from Alamofire, and I got `$ curl command could not be created` for the second one, so clearly, NO, it's not the same... The `encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up here. You are implementing `Decodable` and talking/naming it that way, but what you are doing is `Encoding`.

It seems the Api expects a simple `String` as paramter, constructing it with a `[String: String]` seems ok. But what you are trying to send is `JSON`. I think the request is failing while trying to encode: `["keys": "latlng,time,altitude"]` to your custom struct. Hence the error:

> urlRequestValidationFailed....bodyDataInGETRequest

As has allready been pointed out in the comments you would need to use your old constructor for sending the request.

```
AF.request(url_activity, method: .get, parameters: params, headers: head)
```

then use the method:

```
.responseDecodable(of: "what you expect in the response".self) {
```

Here you need to provide a custom struct that conforms to `Decodable` and represents the ***>"returning json"<***

---

For the request you linked it would be:

```
struct ResponseElement: Codable {
    let type: String
    let data: [Double]
    let seriesType: String
    let originalSize: Int
    let resolution: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type, data
        case seriesType = "series_type"
        case originalSize = "original_size"
        case resolution
    }
}
```

and decoding with:

```
.responseDecodable(of: [ResponseElement].self) {
```

Comment: Many thanks to you and @Larme, it's now working. The  `latlng` key was returning data as an array `[[lat,lng]` whereas the other keys were just returning an array : `[Double]` hence why I had issues decoding these parameters.